# Displaying data from a database in another data type

Tags: c#, .net

so I'm having a problem where I need to take a question field that is in Char and make my site read the data as a int value so it can be properly sorted! not sure how to go about doing it. I Tried converting it and then trying to use that variable but I get errors about wrong overloads.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                questions = questions.Where(q => q.Q_num.Contains(searchString) || q.Q_name.Contains(searchString) || q.VFP_name.Contains(searchString));
            }
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(questions.Select(q => q.Q_num));
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => q.Q_name);
                    break;
                case "name":
                    questions = questions.OrderBy(q => q.Q_name);
                    break;
                case "num_desc":
                    questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => q.Q_num);
                    break;
                default:
                    questions = questions.OrderBy(q => q.Q_num);
                    break;
            }
```

I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression

Comment: Not very clear, what you are really trying to achieve

Comment: you should post the error and where is it in code . but something wrong in your linq query question is something that can have more than one result so you can't have a int value for number.

Comment: what is the error you got please?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: In what context is this code being used?

Comment: how many questions do you have in your database in live environment? because here you should be careful because you are trying to get all search results into memory and apply a sort on them in memory again as I see.

Comment: When you need pagination, this code will not work correctly because you need to do sorting in database by sql, here it seems you are not.

Comment: As of now its like 25 maybe, but there will be more added later. The application I'm building allows the user to create edit or delete questions. I have the questions sorted in the grid view by number and I noticed a problem when question 1 and 10 where next to each other. So I figured the problem is because the data is a string in the database. Thus why I need the value to work like an int so they can be sorted correctly. Unless someone has a better idea

Comment: let me see if removing pagination will work. its not an absolute need but it was nice instead of scrolling for days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `var sorted = questions.OrderBy(q => int.Parse(q.Q_num));`

Comment: I get the following error. I would use int for the datatype but someone already has a visual fox pro application that needs these values to be in either String or Char
 
{LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly here you are trying to make a search from sql db right.

You are writing some c# code and it is converted to sql query by entityframework.

if you write Convert.Toint32(someField) in your c# code it won't be included in your sql query.

As I see here there are 2 options

1. (this is what you are trying) Make search with c# code and let entityframework converts it to sql and brings you results

   problem in this is your integer field is stored as string in database.
   I suggest that change Q_num field's type to integer in database if it stores really integers. Otherwise it will be problematic to convert it in code in memory because it is database concern to sort and search.
2. write a sql query for your search, put your sorting option in sql query depending on your switch case statement and cast numeric values in sql query like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138567/2524010)

`var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.QuestionsTable -- your where clause and sorting options";
    //append order by part in your switch case
    questions.SqlQuery(searchQuery).ToList()`

For the 1st option, you can try this

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    questions = questions.Where(q => q.Q_num.Contains(searchString) || q.Q_name.Contains(searchString) || q.VFP_name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
}

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "name_desc":
        questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => q.Q_name).ToList();
        break;
    case "name":
        questions = questions.OrderBy(q => q.Q_name).ToList();
        break;
    case "num_desc":
        questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => int.Parse(q.Q_num)).ToList();
        break;
    default:
        questions = questions.OrderBy(q => int.Parse(q.Q_num)).ToList();
        break;
}
```

Comment: So if I get an error about a missing cast what would the cast be? and thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Although everyone really tried to answer this question for me and I really appreciate all the good feedback I decided to use some zero placeholders to accommodate the search. I will not say that this is correct it is however a workaround and what someone from work suggested. Otherwise changing the datatype to a double or int and then in the controller having a .tostring so that it can still be searched for.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            questions = questions.Where(q => q.Q_num.ToString().Contains(searchString) || q.Q_name.Contains(searchString) || q.VFP_name.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => q.Q_name);
                break;
            case "name":
                questions = questions.OrderBy(q => q.Q_name);
                break;
            case "num_desc":
                questions = questions.OrderByDescending(q => q.Q_num);
                break;
            default:
                questions = questions.OrderBy(q => q.Q_num);
                break;

        }
```