# PIVOT returns NULL When Converting Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server

Using the following example data:

```
INVNUM  ORDNUM  SHIPNUM INVLINE CHGCODE TAXBODY TAXRATE
I1      O1      0       1       0       36      4.00
I1      O1      0       1       0       51000   4.50
I1      O1      0       1       0       359071  0.37
I2      O2      0       1       0       13      4.00
I2      O2      0       1       0       211      .25
I3      O1      1       1       0       36      4.00
I3      O1      1       1       0       51000   4.50
I3      O1      1       2       A       36      4.00
I3      O1      1       2       A       51000   4.50
I4      O1      0       1       0       359071  6.35
I5      O4      0       1       0       6       6.00
I5      O4      0       1       0       65      0.25
I5      O4      0       1       0       AIHK0   1.00
I5      O4      0       1       0       EMBA0   0.50
I5      O4      0       1       0       EMTQ0   1.00
```

There can be up to 10 TAXBODY rows for each INVNUM, ORDNUM, SHIPNUM, INVLINE, CHGCODE combination.  In other words, there can be up to 10 but there may be less.

Using I2 as an example, I would like the result to be:

```
INVNUM  ORDNUM  SHIPNUM INVLINE CHGCODE TAXBODY0 TAXBODY1...TAXBODY9 TAXRATE0 TAXRATE1...TAXRATE9
I2      O2      0       1       0       13       211        NULL     4.00     .25        NULL
```

I attempted to start small so I could test using PIVOT to get me just the tax rate and I'm getting back NULL in all the TAXRATEx columns.  Here is my SQL statement I used:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [invnum],
    [ordnum],
    [shipnum],
    [taxbody],
    [taxrate]
  FROM #mytable
) TaxDetails
PIVOT (
  AVG([taxrate])
  FOR [taxbody]
  IN (
    [taxrate0],
    [taxrate1],
    [taxrate2],
    [taxrate3],
    [taxrate4],
    [taxrate5],
    [taxrate6],
    [taxrate7],
    [taxrate8],
    [taxrate9]
  )) AS PivotTable
```

I realize it doesn't contain everything I need for my unique combination but again, I was trying to start out small for testing purposes.  When I run the query, I end up with NULL in TAXRATE0 through TAXRATE9.  It also doesn't seem to matter what aggregate function I use, e.g. SUM or MAX.  I've not used PIVOT before so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

I am requesting help figuring out why my SQL statement doesn't work and ultimately would like help, e.g. links or examples, with the following end result:

1. One row with 10 TAXBODY and TAXRATE columns for each INVNUM, ORDNUM, SHIPNUM, INVLINE, CHGCODE combination as mentioned above in the example.
2. The table should allow NULL in the TAXBODYx and TAXRATEx columns where I don't have a value, i.e. I only have 2 tax body rows out of a possible 10.
3. To be able to use the query or a stored procedure to update the appropriate TAXBODY and TAXRATE column(s) in a table that already exists.  The existing table already supports the ability to hold values from multiple TAXBODY and TAXRATE columns.

I've found a couple examples of using PIVOT but they don't seem to work for me.  I'm guessing it's because I don't understand how PIVOT works.  Resources, e.g. links, would be appreciated as well as an explanation if you provide examples to help get me on the right path.

[Basic Example](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/)

[An example that pivots multiple columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kenobonn/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more in the direction you need:

Sample data:

```
declare @tbl table(INVNUM varchar(50),  ORDNUM varchar(50),  SHIPNUM varchar(50), INVLINE varchar(50), CHGCODE varchar(50), TAXBODY varchar(50), TAXRATE decimal(18,2) )
insert into @tbl
select 'I1', 'O1', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '36', '4.00'
union all   select 'I1', 'O1', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '51000','4.50'
union all   select 'I1', 'O1', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '359071', '0.37'
union all   select 'I2', 'O2', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '13', '4.00'
union all   select 'I2', 'O2', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '211', '.25'
union all   select 'I3', 'O1', '1', ' 1', ' 0', '36', '4.00'
union all   select 'I3', 'O1', '1', ' 1', ' 0', '51000', '4.50'
union all   select 'I3', 'O1', '1', ' 2', ' A', '36', '4.00'
union all   select 'I3', 'O1', '1', ' 2', ' A', '51000', '4.50'
union all   select 'I4', 'O1', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '359071', '6.35'
union all   select 'I5', 'O4', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '6', ' 6.00'
union all   select 'I5', 'O4', '0', ' 1', ' 0', '65', '0.25'
union all   select 'I5', 'O4', '0', ' 1', ' 0', 'AIHK0',   '1.00'
union all   select 'I5', 'O4', '0', ' 1', ' 0', 'EMBA0',   '0.50'
union all   select 'I5', 'O4', '0', ' 1', ' 0', 'EMTQ0',   '1.00'
```

For a basic pivot, you need to put actual row values as column names. In your example, this is what you pivot so you have values:

`````
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT [invnum],[ordnum],[shipnum],[taxbody],[taxrate] FROM @tbl) TaxDetails
PIVOT (AVG([taxrate]) FOR [taxbody] IN ([36],[51000],[taxrate2],[taxrate3],[taxrate4],[taxrate5],[taxrate6],[taxrate7],[taxrate8],[taxrate9])) AS PivotTable````
`````

The 2nd link you posted basicly 'creates' 2 new columns on which to pivot data, so that you obtain nice column names.(good link btw).

```
SELECT [invnum],
    [ordnum],
    [shipnum],
    max(taxrate0) as taxrate0,
    max(taxrate1) as taxrate1,
    max(taxrate2) as taxrate2,
    max(taxrate3) as taxrate3,
    max(taxrate4) as taxrate4,
    max(taxrate5) as taxrate5,
    max(taxbody0) as taxbody0,
    max(taxbody1) as taxbody1,
    max(taxbody2) as taxbody2,
    max(taxbody3) as taxbody3,
    max(taxbody4) as taxbody4,
    max(taxbody5) as taxbody5
FROM (
  SELECT
    [invnum],
    [ordnum],
    [shipnum],
    [taxbody],
    [taxrate],
    'taxrate'+ CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [invnum], [ordnum] ORDER BY taxrate ASC)-1 AS NVARCHAR) AS taxratenumber,
    'taxbody'+ CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [invnum], [ordnum] ORDER BY taxrate ASC)-1 AS NVARCHAR) AS taxbodynumber
  FROM @tbl
) TaxDetails
PIVOT (
  AVG([taxrate])
  FOR taxratenumber
  IN ([taxrate0],[taxrate1],[taxrate2],[taxrate3],[taxrate4],[taxrate5],[taxrate6],[taxrate7],[taxrate8],[taxrate9])) AS PivotTable1
PIVOT (
  max([taxBody])
  FOR taxbodynumber
  IN ([taxbody0],[taxbody1],[taxbody2],[taxbody3],[taxbody4],[taxbody5],[taxbody6],[taxbody7],[taxbody8],[taxbody9])) AS PivotTable2
group by invnum, ordnum, shipnum
```

Comment: Because `taxbody` is a `nvarchar` type, it will require an `order by` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138501/sorting-nvarchar-column-as-integer) to preserve the sort order. The requested result has `36` as `taxbody0` instead of `359071` (which is alphabetical sorting for `nvarchar` type).

Comment: honestly i ordered the items on taxrate (i considered it decimal(18,2)). You are correct in your remark but my point was to explain how pivoting would work in this case (and refresh my skills with it ^^ ).

Comment: Mitz and Sander, thank you for the response as well as the examples and explanation.  I will try tomorrow, 7/31/2020, and see what happens.  The challenge is that I don't know what the tax body or tax rates will be which is why I was trying, unsuccessfully, to pivot and create generic column names.  I think I need to use Dynamic SQL which is what I believe the second link shows.  I wasn't having much luck, but I think with the answers I got, I will hopefully be able to make it work.  Also, I voted up @Mitz's answer but because I don't have much rep, it doesn't increase it publicly.

Comment: @Mitz, the second example you gave which was based on the second link I provided, works!.  Thank you very much for the help.  Now, of course, the 3rd party I was dealing with has decided that they can take the taxing bodies and rates as individual rows instead of columns.  <sigh>  If nothing else, thanks to you, I have a new tool in my SQL tool belt.  Thanks again.